# Drag and Drop на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Имеется такой код:

```
  $("body").on('dragenter', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".main_text").html('Отпустите файл');
});
$("body").on('dragleave', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".main_text").html('Перетащите изображение для загрузки');
});
$("body").on("drop", function(event) {
    console.log(1);

    event.preventDefault();

    $(".main_text").html('Начало загрузки...');
    var file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    $(".main_text").html(file.name);
});
```

Первые два события работают, а событие drop просто открывает файл, вместо того , чтобы отобразить его имя. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал хоть и костыль, но он работает.
Вместо всей этой ерунды добавляем

```
<input type="file" class="input_hiden">
```

Задаем ему стиль:

```
.input_hiden{
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999999999999;
top: -880%;
left: 0px;
opacity: 0;}
```

Я выставляю ему размер через js

```
$(".input_hiden").css('height', $(window).height());
$(".input_hiden").css('width', $(window).width());
```

И все, вы прекрасны! 
Drag and Drop работает, не забудьте добавить обработчик :)